# Return row ID created by CockroachDB after a transaction

Tags: go, cockroachdb

After executing a cockroachDB transaction which creates a row, I would like to return that id to my application.

I am currently defining a transaction using the `database/sql` golang package. I then use the `crdb` client to execute the transaction against CockroachDB.

I cannot return anything from the `crdb` transaction except for an error relating to the `crdb` transaction itself. How do people retrieving their most recently created rows if the interface does not provide a way to return a new row id?

I have some transaction that executes two inserts. I get the resulting ids of those inserts and return a response with both of those id values.

```
func myTransaction(ctx context.Context, tx *sql.Tx) (MyTxnResponse, error) {
  var aResult string
  if err := tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, `INSERT INTO foo (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) RETURNING foo_id`).Scan(&aResult); err != nil { ... }

  var bResult string
  if err := tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, `INSERT INTO bar (d,e,f) VALUES (4,5,6) RETURNING bar_id`).Scan(&bResult); err != nil { ... }

  return MyTxnResponse{A: aResult, B: bResult}
}
```

Now, I want to execute the transaction against CRDB

```
var responseStruct MyTxnResponse
err := crdb.ExecuteTx(ctx.Background(), db, nil, func(tx *sql.Tx) error {
    res, err := myTransaction(ctx,tx)

    // This is what I am currently doing... it seems bad
    responseStruct.A = res.A
    responseStruct.B = res.B

    return err
}
... use responseStruct for something
```

I am able to get the result of the transaction by using this external var solution and just mutating it's state in the closure, but that seems like a really bad pattern. I'm sure I'm missing something that will blow up in my face if I keep this pattern.

Is there a standard way to return something from a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea: declare variables outside the transaction and assign them inside the transaction closure. This is the idiomatic way to "return" things in Go from a closure like this, since the only alternative is to have the function return an `interface{}` which would need a runtime cast to be useful.

There are a couple of shortcuts available here: since `responseStruct` and `res` are the same type, you don't need to list all the fields. You can simply say `responseStruct = res`.

You can even assign the result of `myTransaction` directly to `responseStruct`, avoiding the temporary `res` entirely. However, you have to be careful with your variable scopes here - you can't use `:=` because that would create a new `responseStruct` inside the closure. Instead, you must declare all *other* variables (here, `err`) so that you can use the plain `=` assignment:

```
var responseStruct MyTxnResponse
err := crdb.ExecuteTx(context.Background(), db, nil, func(tx *sql.Tx) error {
    var err error
    responseStruct, err = myTransaction(ctx, tx)
    return err
})
// use responseStruct (but only if err is nil)
```